# React Typescript. Mapping an array inside an object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I'm new at this and I was wondering how I can map this API on here. Here is my process so far. What I want is the what inside the products Array, productName and so on... I first though that `"FC<IFavourite> = ({products.productName,products.manufacture }) => {}"` and so on would but I was wrong.

here is the issue message i'm getting from console. "objects are not valid as a React child `(found: object with keys {id, productName, manufacture, description, price, image})`. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead".

```
{
  "id": "61918c0d4621bd8f4c92100a",
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "618c006adb54f484fb60eac1",
      "productName": "ZX 500 UNISEX - Joggesko",
      "manufacture": "Addidas Originals",
      "description": "Skotupp: Rund\nHælform: Flat\nLukking: Snøring\nArtikkelnummer: AD115O0U6-A11",
      "price": "999.00",
      "image": "60dae73f9340481cb5ff8f58a24e5554.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
import React, { FC } from "react"
import { IFavourite, IProducts } from "../../interfaces/Interfaces"



const FavouriteItem: FC<IFavourite> = ({products}) => {
 
  return (
    <div>
        <h3>{products}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FavouriteItem
```

```
import React, { FC, useContext } from "react"
import { FavouriteContext } from "../../context/context"
import { IFavourite } from "../../interfaces/Interfaces"
import { FavouriteType } from "../../types/Types"
import { Products } from "../../views"
import FavouriteItem from "./FavouriteItem"

const FavouriteList: FC = () => {
  const { favourite } = useContext(FavouriteContext) as FavouriteType

  const FavouriteList = () => { 
    return favourite.map((product: IFavourite, key: number) => { 
      return <div>
          <FavouriteItem 
          key={key}
          products={product.products}
          />

        
      </div>
    })
  }
  return <div>{FavouriteList()}</div>
}

export default FavouriteList
```

Comment: Does the variable `favorite` have the content of that first snippet of JSON? Do you get any errors? What problems are you encountering, specifically?

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to display "products" object itself, which is not possible, objects are not valid as a React child. You need to display primitive value like string, number.

```
 
  return (
    <div>
        <h3>{products.id}</h3> // you need to display all required product properties and not object itself
        <span>{products.productName}</span> //similar for other product properties
    </div>
  )
}
```